# Flutter table calendar not correctly mapping events from API

Tags: flutter, dart

so i'm using Flutter Clean Architecture by Uncle bob and i want to implement the [Flutter table_calender](https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar) package. From the API i receive this response and i filter what i need with `var responseBody = jsonDecode(response.body)['datas'];`

## REST API response

```
{
  "datas": [
    {
    "id": 3,
    "createdBy": "admin",
    "createdDate": 1621779345.108107000,
    "lastModifiedBy": "admin",
    "lastModifiedDate": 1621787873.353633000,
    "vendeur": {
        "id": 2,
        "createdBy": "admin",
        "createdDate": 1620785642.893905000,
        "lastModifiedBy": "admin",
        "lastModifiedDate": 1620785642.893905000,
        "code": "2367",
        "name": "Mohsen cherif",
        "status": false
    },
    "tournee": {
        "id": 2,
        "createdBy": "admin",
        "createdDate": 1620786506.849305000,
        "lastModifiedBy": "admin",
        "lastModifiedDate": 1620786506.849305000,
        "code": "102",
        "name": "tournée tunis vile",
        "typeProduits": "divers",
        "delegations": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "gouvernorat": "Tunis",
                "label": "Bab Bhar"
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "gouvernorat": "Tunis",
                "label": "Bardo"
            }
        ],
        "clients": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "createdBy": "admin",
                "createdDate": 1620785240.161326000,
                "lastModifiedBy": "admin",
                "lastModifiedDate": 1620785240.161326000,
                "code": "165",
                "name": "Hichem Ben Amor",
                "adresse": "qsdfqs",
                "delegations": "Bardo",
                "latitude": 36.80019113029345,
                "longitude": 10.184562696785417,
                "status": false
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "createdBy": "admin",
                "createdDate": 1620785562.500062000,
                "lastModifiedBy": "admin",
                "lastModifiedDate": 1620785562.500062000,
                "code": "69",
                "name": "Youssef el Abed",
                "adresse": "bardo",
                "delegations": "Menzah",
                "latitude": 36.80769081225629,
                "longitude": 10.136253081449054,
                "status": false
            }
        ],
        "status": true
    },
    "date": 1621983600000,
    "type": "MORNING",
    "geolocation": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "createdBy": "admin",
            "createdDate": null,
            "lastModifiedBy": null,
            "lastModifiedDate": null,
            "client": {
                "id": 2,
                "createdBy": "admin",
                "createdDate": 1620785562.500062000,
                "lastModifiedBy": "admin",
                "lastModifiedDate": 1620785562.500062000,
                "code": "69",
                "name": "Youssef el Abed",
                "adresse": "bardo",
                "delegations": "Menzah",
                "latitude": 36.80769081225629,
                "longitude": 10.136253081449054,
                "status": false
            },
            "latitude": 33.35465517486007,
            "longitude": 8.675682229056365
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "createdBy": "admin",
            "createdDate": null,
            "lastModifiedBy": null,
            "lastModifiedDate": null,
            "client": {
                "id": 1,
                "createdBy": "admin",
                "createdDate": 1620785240.161326000,
                "lastModifiedBy": "admin",
                "lastModifiedDate": 1620785240.161326000,
                "code": "165",
                "name": "Hichem Ben Amor",
                "adresse": "qsdfqs",
                "delegations": "Bardo",
                "latitude": 36.80019113029345,
                "longitude": 10.184562696785417,
                "status": false
            },
            "latitude": 35.54390530467798,
            "longitude": 10.826683449076553
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "createdBy": "admin",
            "createdDate": null,
            "lastModifiedBy": null,
            "lastModifiedDate": null,
            "client": {
                "id": 1,
                "createdBy": "admin",
                "createdDate": 1620785240.161326000,
                "lastModifiedBy": "admin",
                "lastModifiedDate": 1620785240.161326000,
                "code": "165",
                "name": "Hichem Ben Amor",
                "adresse": "qsdfqs",
                "delegations": "Bardo",
                "latitude": 36.80019113029345,
                "longitude": 10.184562696785417,
                "status": false
            },
            "latitude": 36.800810869328565,
            "longitude": 10.13147767920817
        }
    ],
    "done": true
},
    {another object},
    {another object}
  ],
  "totalRecords": 5
}
```

then i converted this json response to a Dart class using this website [app.quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io/)

## planning.dart

```
Planning planningFromJson(String str) => Planning.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String planningToJson(Planning data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Planning {
  Planning({
    this.id,
    this.createdBy,
    this.createdDate,
    this.lastModifiedBy,
    this.lastModifiedDate,
    this.vendeur,
    this.tournee,
    this.date,
    this.type,
    this.geolocation,
    this.done,
  });

  int id;
  String createdBy;
  double createdDate;
  String lastModifiedBy;
  double lastModifiedDate;
  Vendeur vendeur;
  Tournee tournee;
  int date;
  String type;
  List<Geolocation> geolocation;
  bool done;

  factory Planning.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Planning(
        id: json["id"],
        createdBy: json["createdBy"],
        createdDate: json["createdDate"].toDouble(),
        lastModifiedBy: json["lastModifiedBy"],
        lastModifiedDate: json["lastModifiedDate"].toDouble(),
        vendeur: Vendeur.fromJson(json["vendeur"]),
        tournee: Tournee.fromJson(json["tournee"]),
        date: json["date"],
        type: json["type"],
        geolocation: List<Geolocation>.from(
            json["geolocation"].map((x) => Geolocation.fromJson(x))),
        done: json["done"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "createdBy": createdBy,
        "createdDate": createdDate,
        "lastModifiedBy": lastModifiedBy,
        "lastModifiedDate": lastModifiedDate,
        "vendeur": vendeur.toJson(),
        "tournee": tournee.toJson(),
        "date": date,
        "type": type,
        "geolocation": List<dynamic>.from(geolocation.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "done": done,
      };
}
```

Using clean architecture i receiver from the controller a List<'Planning'>
So in the view i have this

## PlanningView

```
class PlanningPageView extends ViewState<PlanningPage, PlanningController>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  PlanningPageView(PlanningController controller) : super(controller);
  CalendarController _calendarController;
  AnimationController _animationController;
  List<Planning> _selectedEvents;
  DateTime selectedDay;
  Map<DateTime, List<Planning>> _events;

  getListPlanning() {
    List<Planning> plannings = controller.listPlannings;
    final result = plannings
        .map<Planning>((json) => Planning.fromJson(json))
        .toList();
    return result;
  }


  Map<DateTime, List<dynamic>> getTask1() {
    Map<DateTime, List<Planning>> mapFetch = {};
    List<Planning> planning = getListPlanning();
    print("hello before loop");
//the date is a timestamp so i need to convert it.
    for (int i = 0; i < planning.length; i++) {
      var date = new DateTime(
          DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(planning[i].date).year,
          DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(planning[i].date).month,
          DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(planning[i].date).day);
      log(date.toString());
      var original = mapFetch[date];
        print(planning[i]..tournee.name);
        mapFetch[date] = List.from(original)..addAll([planning[i]..tournee.name]);
      }
    }

    return mapFetch;
  }
  void _onDaySelected(DateTime day, List events) {
    print('CALLBACK: _onDaySelected');
    setState(() {
      _selectedEvents = events;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    //final _selectedDay = DateTime.now();
    _selectedEvents = [];
    _calendarController = CalendarController();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400),
    );

    _animationController.forward();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      getTask1();
           .then((val) => setState(() {
             _events = val;
           }));
      //print(' ${_events.toString()} ');
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _calendarController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WidgetHelper.buildView(
        context,
        globalKey,
        VisibilityDetector(
            key: Key("PlanningPageView"),
            onVisibilityChanged: (VisibilityInfo info) {
              controller.visibilityChanged(info);
            },
            child: body),
        controller);
  }

  Stack get body => Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              _buildTableCalendarWithBuilders(),
              const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
              const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
              Expanded(child: _buildEventList()),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      );

  Widget _buildTableCalendarWithBuilders() {
    return TableCalendar(
      // locale: 'fr_FR',
      calendarController: _calendarController,
      events: _events,
      //holidays: _holidays,
      initialCalendarFormat: CalendarFormat.month,
      formatAnimation: FormatAnimation.slide,
      startingDayOfWeek: StartingDayOfWeek.sunday,
      availableGestures: AvailableGestures.all,
      availableCalendarFormats: const {
        CalendarFormat.month: '',
        CalendarFormat.week: '',
      },
      calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
        outsideDaysVisible: false,
        weekendStyle: TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.blue[800]),
        holidayStyle: TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.blue[800]),
      ),
      daysOfWeekStyle: DaysOfWeekStyle(
        weekendStyle: TextStyle().copyWith(color: Colors.blue[600]),
      ),
      headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
        centerHeaderTitle: true,
        formatButtonVisible: false,
      ),
      builders: CalendarBuilders(
        selectedDayBuilder: (context, date, _) {
          return FadeTransition(
            opacity: Tween(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(_animationController),
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, left: 6.0),
              color: Colors.deepOrange[300],
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              child: Text(
                '${date.day}',
                style: TextStyle().copyWith(fontSize: 16.0),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
        todayDayBuilder: (context, date, _) {
          return Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, left: 6.0),
            color: Colors.amber[400],
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            child: Text(
              '${date.day}',
              style: TextStyle().copyWith(fontSize: 16.0),
            ),
          );
        },
        markersBuilder: (context, date, events, holidays) {
          final children = <Widget>[];

          if (events.isNotEmpty) {
            children.add(
              Positioned(
                right: 1,
                bottom: 1,
                child: _buildEventsMarker(date, events),
              ),
            );
          }

          if (holidays.isNotEmpty) {
            children.add(
              Positioned(
                right: -2,
                top: -2,
                child: _buildHolidaysMarker(),
              ),
            );
          }

          return children;
        },
      ),
      onDaySelected: (date, events, holidays) {
        _onDaySelected(date, events);
        _animationController.forward(from: 0.0);
      },
      onVisibleDaysChanged: _onVisibleDaysChanged,
    );
  }

  void _onVisibleDaysChanged(
      DateTime first, DateTime last, CalendarFormat format) {
    print('CALLBACK: _onVisibleDaysChanged');
  }

  Widget _buildEventsMarker(DateTime date, List events) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
        color: _calendarController.isSelected(date)
            ? Colors.brown[500]
            : _calendarController.isToday(date)
                ? Colors.brown[300]
                : Colors.blue[400],
      ),
      width: 16.0,
      height: 16.0,
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          '${events.length}',
          style: TextStyle().copyWith(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 12.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildHolidaysMarker() {
    return Icon(
      Icons.add_box,
      size: 20.0,
      color: Colors.blueGrey[800],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildEventList() {
    return ListView(
      children: _selectedEvents
          .map((planning) => Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(width: 0.8),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                ),
                margin:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 4.0),
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(planning.tournee.name.toString()),
                  /// to uncomment after fixing the controller return type
                  onTap: () => {controller.openPlanning(planning)},
                  // onTap: () => {Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/planning', arguments: {
                  // 'planning': planning
                  // })},
                ),
              ))
          .toList(),
    );
  }
}
}
```

The Android studio debug is not showing anything also in my phone the calendar is empty!
Ps: i'm new with flutter, i've followed https://gist.github.com/zgramming/fcc8d6585cecb7ece5c5c7088c7e421f#gistcomment-3181699 but it didn't work with my case ‍♂️

Comment: Are you having "eventLoader" in your calendar's parameters?

Comment: @ExtremeGeek whene i'm working with a json format like in the gist link, it's working perfectly but whene i changed the source to controller.listPlannings it didn't work